# TypeError: table.select(...).then is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
exports.checkWhitelist = (emailToCheck) => {
  //calls Airtable using req email
  table.select({
    filterByFormula: {email}=emailToCheck
  }).then(res => {
    if (!Array.isArray(res.records) || !res.records.length) {
      res.send({
        "Success":false,
        "responseCode":403
      })
      return True
  }
  }
  )
};
```

This function checks a passed in email against a whitelist in Airtable. The .select method calls the specific table (the whitelist) and passes in the emailToCheck as a parameter. If the response from Airtable is an empty array, I know the email is not on our whitelist. Otherwise, the function should return True.

The error I am getting is: TypeError: table.select(...).then is not a function - what am I getting wrong?

Comment: You are not returning a promise from `table.select` function

Comment: somehow   table.select is not returning promise. 

Please check  table.select()  method must return a Promise object.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Javascript to interact with databases much, nor am I experienced in promises, however most likely what happened is that `table.select` does not return a promise, maybe check the value `emailToCheck` and the operatations on that value, if its not the solution at least it's a start.